# Convert date formats in bash

Tags: linux, bash, date, awk

I have a date in this format:  "27 JUN 2011" and I want to convert it to 20110627

Is it possible to do in bash?

Comment: In case it's not obvious, the answers with `date -d` generally apply to GNU `date` (so, most Linux platforms) while e.g. BSD and thus MacOS support different options and facilities. For complete portability, you want to restrict yourself to [POSIX `date`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html), which doesn't really support meaningful conversions between date formats.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
#since this was yesterday
date -dyesterday +%Y%m%d

#more precise, and more recommended
date -d'27 JUN 2011' +%Y%m%d

#assuming this is similar to yesterdays `date` question from you 
#http://stackoverflow.com/q/6497525/638649
date -d'last-monday' +%Y%m%d

#going on @seth's comment you could do this
DATE="27 jun 2011"; date -d"$DATE" +%Y%m%d

#or a method to read it from stdin
read -p "  Get date >> " DATE; printf "  AS YYYYMMDD format >> %s"  `date
-d"$DATE" +%Y%m%d`    

#which then outputs the following:
#Get date >> 27 june 2011   
#AS YYYYMMDD format >> 20110627

#if you really want to use awk
echo "27 june 2011" | awk '{print "date -d\""$1FS$2FS$3"\" +%Y%m%d"}' | bash

#note | bash just redirects awk's output to the shell to be executed
#FS is field separator, in this case you can use $0 to print the line
#But this is useful if you have more than one date on a line
```

[More on Dates](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats)

note this only works on GNU date

I have read that:

> Solaris version of date, which is unable
>   to support `-d` can be resolve with
>   replacing sunfreeware.com version of
>   date

Answer (score 20):

On OSX, I'm using -f to specify the input format, -j to not attempt to set any date, and an output format specifier. For example:

```
$ date -j -f "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %p" "8/22/15 8:15:00 am" +"%m%d%y"
082215
```

Your example:

```
$ date -j -f "%d %b %Y" "27 JUN 2011" +%Y%m%d
20110627
```

Comment: Very helpful. `date` seems to behave quirky on macOS

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for Linux (at least `date` on Ubuntu 22.10 fails with `invalid option -j`)

Answer (score 15):

```
date -d "25 JUN 2011" +%Y%m%d
```

outputs

```
20110625
```

Answer (score 10):

If you would like a bash function that works both on Mac OS X and Linux:

```sh
#
# Convert one date format to another
# 
# Usage: convert_date_format <input_format> <date> <output_format>
#
# Example: convert_date_format '%b %d %T %Y %Z' 'Dec 10 17:30:05 2017 GMT' '%Y-%m-%d'
convert_date_format() {
  local INPUT_FORMAT="$1"
  local INPUT_DATE="$2"
  local OUTPUT_FORMAT="$3"
  local UNAME=$(uname)

  if [[ "$UNAME" == "Darwin" ]]; then
    # Mac OS X
    date -j -f "$INPUT_FORMAT" "$INPUT_DATE" +"$OUTPUT_FORMAT"
  elif [[ "$UNAME" == "Linux" ]]; then
    # Linux
    date -d "$INPUT_DATE" +"$OUTPUT_FORMAT"
  else
    # Unsupported system
    echo "Unsupported system"
  fi
}

# Example: 'Dec 10 17:30:05 2017 GMT' => '2017-12-10'
convert_date_format '%b %d %T %Y %Z' 'Dec 10 17:30:05 2017 GMT' '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Answer (score 7):

Just with bash:

```
convert_date () {
    local months=( JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC )
    local i
    for (( i=0; i<11; i++ )); do
        [[ $2 = ${months[$i]} ]] && break
    done
    printf "%4d%02d%02d\n" $3 $(( i+1 )) $1
}
```

And invoke it like this

```
d=$( convert_date 27 JUN 2011 )
```

Or if the "old" date string is stored in a variable

```
d_old="27 JUN 2011"
d=$( convert_date $d_old )  # not quoted
```

Answer (score 4):

It's enough to do:

```
data=`date`
datatime=`date -d "${data}" '+%Y%m%d'`
echo $datatime
20190206
```

If you want to add also the time you can use in that way

```
data=`date`
datatime=`date -d "${data}" '+%Y%m%d %T'`

echo $data
Wed Feb 6 03:57:15 EST 2019

echo $datatime
20190206 03:57:15
```

Comment: It reports :

    date: invalid date ‘Thu 18 Mar 11:58:32 GMT 2021’

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something changed since 2011 but this worked for me:

```
$ date +"%Y%m%d"
20150330
```

No need for the `-d` to get the same appearing result.

Comment: -d sets the date you want to format.  Without it, date formats the current date.