# Convert MM-DD-YY MM:SS to YY-MM-DD MM:SS

Tags: shell, unix, date

I want to convert a date like

```
12-24-11 13:37
```

(MM-DD-YY MM:SS) to

```
11-12-24 13:37
```

(YY-MM-DD MM:SS)

is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed to the rescue:

```
$ echo 12-24-11 13:37 | sed 's#^\([0-9\-]\{5\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)#\2-\1#'
11-12-24 13:37
```

Answer (score 1):

No sed needed.

```
#!/bin/sh

input="12-24-11 13:37";

month="${input%%-*}";
input="${input#*-}";

day="${input%%-*}";
input="${input#*-}";

year="${input%% *}";
input="${input#* }";

echo "$year-$month-$day $input";
```

But if you do want to use external tools, might as well use one with a *short* regex

```
echo 12-24-11 13:37 | perl -pe 's/(.+)-(.+) /$2-$1 /'
```

Comment: I switched around `$2` and `$1` in the perl version, since it is otherwise a NOP.

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/

Comment: afaik, `date` can just print the current date, or *set* a new date. The OP wants to format an existing date.

Comment: @phihag If the OP used date, his invocation of date would either already include the + (to generate %m-%d-%Y), or his input would be something like "Sat Dec 24" (not %m-%d-%Y at all) instead :)

Comment: @phihag: Technically, `date` *can* usually print any arbitrary date. GNU date uses `-d` flag for this purpose, BSD date uses `-r` and `-v`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash is a good answer which seems to cover most basis