# Convert YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+/-HH:MM date in bash

Tags: bash, date, sed, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert date formats in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash)

I need to convert a date such as

```
2012-06-01T19:05:00+02:00
```

to something like this

```
01-06-2012 19:05
```

Ideally using **sed** or **awk**. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't tell me how to do it. I did find that post before but I'm to stupid to make it work.

Comment: Please improve questions like this by showing why whatever you tried isn't working. Otherwise, `man 1 date` is your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "2012-06-01T19:05:00+02:00"|sed 's/\(.*\)T\([0-9]*:[0-9]*\).*/\1 \2/'
2012-06-01 19:05
```

To explain what it does:

- match everything up to the T and refer to it as \1 later
- match any following digits, followed by a ":", followed by any following digits and refer to that group as \2
- print first match, space, second match

Answer (score 5):

This can be done without resorting to sed or awk, since bash itself can do most of the required string replacements. Specifically, you just need to:

1. replace **T** with a space, and
2. remove your timezone information.

The rest of the date formatting can be handled by the **date** command.

```
$ date_string='2012-06-01T19:05:00+02:00'
$ date_string="${date_string/T/ }"
$ date_string="${date_string/+*/}"
$ date -d "$date_string" '+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'
01-06-2012 19:05
```

Comment: The square brackets aren't necessary around the "T". The quotes can be omitted around the parameter expansions.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson You're right. I'd originally had a more complicated expression which included a character class. I've gone ahead and removed the character class, as well as an extraneous space in one of the original replacement expressions, to make the intent more clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
date -d "$(echo '2012-06-01T19:05:00+02:00' | sed 's/T/ /; s/+.*//')" '+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'
```