# How can I suppress (g)awk compatibility warnings?

Tags: awk, gawk

I want to use some `gawk` extensions to the `awk` standard, for example `mktime()`. At the same time, I want to use the option `--lint=fatal` because I'd rather let the process fail than have it produce potentially incorrect data silently. However, there is something I do not understand:

```
$ gawk --lint=fatal 'BEGIN { foo = mktime("2013 01 01 12 00 00"); }' 
gawk: cmd. line:1: fatal: `mktime' is a gawk extension
```

I did *not* specify the options `--posix` or `--traditional`, so the `gawk` extensions should be present. Once I reduce the strictness (`--lint=warning`), the script works. In order to use the strict checks, I would have to tell `gawk` something like *I know that I'm using your extended function set and that I'm no longer compatible with the original `awk` specification, and I'm fine with that.* How can I do this?

Comment: That's probably the most annoying issue in gawk. --lint would have been very useful for catching undefined variables if it wasn't pestering me about the use of ENDFILE, a must have feature for me. It's still an issue in gawk 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done from `awk` itself. From `man gawk` version 4.1.0, May 9th 2013:

> --lint[=value]
>
> Provide warnings about constructs that are dubious or non-portable to other AWK implementations.  With an optional argument
>   of fatal,
>                 lint  warnings  become  fatal  errors.  This may be drastic, but its use will certainly encourage the development of
>   cleaner AWK pro‐
>                 grams.  With an optional argument of invalid, only warnings about things that are actually invalid are issued.  (This  is
>   not  fully
>                 implemented yet.)

You could write a simple wrapper script to parse `stderr` and only display the warning you want to see.

Comment: The problem is not the display of the warnings, the problem is that I want `make` to abort whenever, let's say, a `substr()` runs past the end of the input file...

Comment: How about sticking with `--lint` and replace calls to `gawk` functions like `mktime()` with system calls i.e. `system("date")` ect.

Comment: That would be an option - just what would I do about `strftime()`?

Comment: Use `date` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this wrapper for gawk

```
#! /bin/bash
AWK="/usr/bin/gawk --lint"
exec 3>&1
set -o pipefail
$AWK "$@" 2>&1 1>&3 | { grep -v 'is a gawk extension$' || test $? = 1; }
```

File descriptor 3 becomes a copy of stdout. When gawk is run, its stdout goes to the copied file descriptor (i.e. stdout). The stderr of gawk goes to stdout and through a pipe to grep, and then the grep output is sent back to stderr.

If gawk fails, the script exits with its error code due to the `pipefail` option. If grep fails to produce output (i.e. it fileter out all warnings), the script still succeeds. For other grep errors, the script fails.

Save the wrapper as `gawk` or `awk` somewhere in your PATH and make sure that directory appears in PATH before `/usr/bin`.

Now you have a smart awk that only warns about the issues you care about.