# how to convert given date to customized date in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I am completely new to shell scripting.
I need to change the format of given date to customized format like i have date in a variable with format as MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS but i want date in a format as MM/DD/YYY HH:MM:SS which is having four digits of the year.
We can change the sys date format but i need  the same in a variable.
My code as below

```
START_DATE="12/20/14 05:59:01"
yr=`echo $START_DATE | cut -d ' ' -f1 | cut -d '/' -f3`
yr_len=`echo $yr | wc -c`
if [ $yr_len -lt 4 ]
then
    tmp_yr="20${yr}";
else
    1=1;
fi
ln=`echo $tmp_yr|wc -c`
```

After this i strucked in reframe the same date in wanted format.

Can some one please help me

Regards,
Sai.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash) for details on doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU date:

```
date -d'02/16/15 09:16:04' "+%m/%d/%Y %T"
```

produces

```
02/16/2015 09:16:04
```

which is what you want. See `man date` for details about the formatting, or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash) for a number of great examples.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but when i use this command , i am getting some error as date: illegal option -- d

Comment: The `-d` option only works with GNU date. Are you working on Mac or GNU/Linux, or something else?

Comment: I am working in GMT. Not in GNU. Could you please suggest me anothe way

Comment: No, `GNU date` is the program, and it works fine with GMT times. What is your `date` program? You can see it if you type `date --version`

Comment: I didnt get my date program. I am getting the same result for given command as well. I entered as: date --version 
Tried with different combinations but no luck :(

Comment: No, type `date --version` on its own, so that you can see what version your `date` program is. It is the wrong version, you need to update it, or install the right one, as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash) mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

One option may be using the date/time functions inside awk. Here is a oneliner:

```
echo '02/16/15 09:16:04' | sed 's\[/:]\ \g' | awk '{d0=$3+2000FS$1FS$2FS$4FS$5FS$6; d1=mktime(d0);print strftime("%m/%d/%Y %T", d1) }'
```

output is:

```
02/16/2015 09:16:04
```

You can find more strftime formats in https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html