# convert string ddmmyyyy to yymmdd using linux

Tags: linux, text, awk, sed

I am struggling to convert a textfile which contains the string:

```
10.04.2015 12:00:15
```

to

```
150410
```

The date will always be the date format but is taken from a textfile so as far as I know I can't use a date command and I think I must use awk but I don't know it well and am struggling - advice would be appreciated?

Comment: Note that the formats in your title are different to the ones in your input / desired output.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash

Comment: Cheers, I'll take the advice and use the one with more options for later use.

Comment: If it's the only data in the file then e.g. `awk '{ print substr($0, 7, 2) substr($0, 3, 2) substr($0, 1, 2) }'` but realistically, we need to understand what else there is in the file. Show us a real representative sample input and the desired output.

Comment: If you could get rid of the dots and replace them with slashes, `date -d"10/04/2015 12:00:15" "+%y%d%m"` makes it.

Comment: `sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.\([0-9][0-9]*\).[0-9][0-9]\([0-9][0-9]\)/\3\2\1/'` would do the work. No space to write a complete response filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to extract substrings

```
$ date="10.04.2015 12:00:15"
$ newdate=${date:8:2}${date:3:2}${date:0:2}
$ echo $newdate
150410
```

Comment: Looks like the best of all alternatives (if the shell is `bash`)

Comment: ...and the input is a string, rather than a file (which I don't think is the case here)

Comment: @hek2mgl, and ksh93 and zsh

Comment: Thanks, I did indeed go for this solution, the input is a string and I do use bash but ultimately I used this one as it is simply the easiest to see how it works.  I am too new to sed/awk and regex's to fully understand everything but the parameter expansion is easily readable and easier to follow.  Thanks, thanks for your help too Tom.

Answer (score 1):

The following `sed` command should be good enough:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]+:?){3}/\3\2\1/g' input
```

or `awk`:

```
awk -F'[.: ]' '{print substr($3,3),$2,$1}' OFS='' input
```

After all I prefer the latter.

Comment: I ultimately went for the above siolution as it is simply easier to use for a beginner - note I tested these and they do the job nicely too.  Thanks for the help/advice.

Answer (score 0):

alternative answer, using awk:

```
DATE="10.04.2015 12:00:15"
echo $DATE | awk '{print substr($0,9,2) substr($0,4,2) substr($0,1,2)}'
```

Some explanation if you want to do modifications later:

- `$0` is the input text on which substr operates
- the the first digit is where the substring starts
- the second digit indicates the length of the substring

Comment: be carefull about *which contains the string* whre your code need a first extraction before occuring if it is inside a bigger string. Mybe assume that string to treat is only with this information