# How to convert dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss to yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss using linux?

Tags: linux, date, datetime, strftime

I want to convert epoch like "26/11/05 06:00:01,057000000" to yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss using linux?

I have tried using the following script with no luck:

```
echo 26/11/05 06:00:01,057000000 | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$1) }'
```

Output:

```
1970-01-01 01:00:26
```

Comment: This [Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash) may help you with a clear answar.

Comment: where is the part where you try to parse the incoming date ?

Comment: What is 26/11/05? Is that 26 November 2005, or 5 November 2026, or something else? And is the ",057000000" the decimal part of the seconds?

Comment: 26 November 2005 and yes it's the decimal but it can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from datetime import datetime

time_string = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
dt = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S,%f000')
print(dt.isoformat())
```

Example (save the above code to `convert-time-format` and run
`chmod +x convert-time-format`):

```sh
$ ./convert-time-format 26/11/05 06:00:01,057000000
2005-11-26T06:00:01.057000
```