# Convert date from column in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

My file looks like this:

```
ID,DATE,NAME
1,10-17-18,John
2,10-12-18,Mary
3,10-19-18,David
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
1,2018-10-17,John
2,2018-10-12,Mary
3,2018-10-19,David
```

How can I do that in bash?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6508849/9799449

Comment: Did you make any attempt?

Comment: I need a solution that doesn't modify line by line because I have over 90k lines. I need something to modify the entire column.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question... [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow). You are expected to make an effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Delimit by ',' `-F','`.
Skip the first line `(NR>1)`.
Replace - in date string with /, `gsub(/-/,"/",$2)` so date will recognize the format 
as month/day/year.
Convert date format, save as variable d `("date +%Y-%m-%d -d"$2 | getline d)`.
Then print each field separated by comma.

```
awk -F',' '(NR>1){gsub(/-/,"/",$2); ("date +%Y-%m-%d -d"$2 | getline d); print $1","d","$3}' file
```

To skip lines with blank dates, add `if($2=="") next;` at the start, like this:

```
awk -F',' '(NR>1){if($2=="") next; gsub(/-/,"/",$2); ("date +%Y-%m-%d -d"$2 | getline d); print $1","d","$3}' file
```

Comment: It worked, but: 
date: option requires an argument -- 'd'
Try 'date --help' for more information.

Comment: That likely means one of the rows has an empty value in column 2.

Comment: How can I ignore blank values in column 2, but keep converting?

Comment: Please see edit.