# Format date in shell script YYYY-MM-DD +DAY + Mounth

Tags: bash, shell, date

I tried using `$(date)`in my bash shell script, however I want the date in `YYYY-MM-DD +DAY + Mounth` format.(if the month is 9 I do not want to display 09) How do I get this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date formats in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash)

Comment: So would today be `2019-09-17 +17 +9`?

Comment: 2019-09-17 Tuesday September ,but I want to display in whatever language I want. I have this :  `date "+%A %B %d %T %y" `

Comment: Hmm, so where does the _if the month is 9 I do not want to display 09_ come to picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some versions of `date` can't display the month without the leading zero. You can use `sed` to remove it, though: the month is the only number surrounded by dashes:

```
date '+%Y-%m-%d %A %B' | sed 's/-0\([0-9]\)-/-\1-/'
```

Some versions support the padding modifiers. To turn padding off, use a dash:

```
date '+%Y-%-m-%d %A %B'
           ~
```

To change the language, just specify the locale:

```
$ LC_ALL=it_IT.UTF-8 date '+%Y-%m-%d %A %B' | sed 's/-0\([0-9]\)-/-\1-/'
2019-9-17 martedì settembre
```

Comment: What parameters i need to change  to display what language i want.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the solution.

Comment: One more question.
What can i do when i have the code in this format`LC_ALL=it_IT.UTF-8 date '+%Y-%m %B-%d %A' | sed 's/-0\([0-9]\)-/-\1-/'
`

Comment: 2019-09 settembre-17 martedì   in this situation I would like to stay 9

Comment: Either specify `%-m` if your version of `date` supports it, or remove the dash between a digit and zero: `sed 's/\([0-9]\)-0/\1-/'`.