# Cannot format date in bash mac

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

input: `$ date -d '13 JAN 1995' +%A`
output:

```
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

expected output: `Friday`
.

First I thought this is because of my older version of bash 3.x but later I upgraded to 5.0. Still having this problem.

I read here for date formats [Convert date formats in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
date -j -f '%d %b %Y' '+%A' '13 JAN 1995'
```

MacOS comes with BSD date, but your command is designed to work with GNU date.
Take a look at [BSD strftime(3)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strftime&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports) before fiddling with the format.