# How to convert date in Macbook (Terminal)?

Tags: macos, date, terminal, date-formatting

I need to convert the date of the macbook via CLI because I'm running a script:

Date we have to convert 2019-09-17 15:32:27

Final format Jun 17 15:32:27

I tried it with the following script:

```
date_raw=`grep "^.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,"$i"," ${SNIFFER_BUFFER_USAGE} | head -1 | awk -F ',' '{ print $2}'`
if [ $OSX -eq 1 ];
then
  dataHoraMinuto=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "$date_raw" +"%b %d %H:%M:%S")
else
  dataHoraMinuto=`date +"%b %d %H:%M:%S" -d "$date_raw"`
fi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date formats in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash)

Comment: You need to _format_ the date, not “convert” it. How you do that depends upon what programming language you are using.

Comment: @matt Okay, so a using bash, could you please help me a format this date? Thanks man!

Comment: @TomášPospíšek Actually it doesn't help, at least what I tried on my side because it brings all the timestamp and I just need a part! Can you help me?

Comment: Please show what you tried (exact commands, input you provided, output you got), that makes it easier to help.

Comment: So `man date` and read about the format string.

Comment: @cello Yes man, no problem! I tried to format but it was strange, so follow the link:
https://pastebin.com/raw/apYyANPS

Thanks

Comment: your command seems to work, at least when I use `date_raw="2019-09-17 15:32:27"` in the script instead of the grep expression. Did you verify that the grep returns the expected part? e.g. add a `echo $date_raw` to your script and check the output.