# Formatting date strings in a file with linux bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

When I cat the file an example of the output format is:

```
ok: servername Mon May 23 00:00:00 EDT 2018
ok: servername Thu Jul 16 00:00:00 EDT 2019
```

I would like the format to be something like

```
ok: servername 05/23/2018
ok: servername 07/16/2019
```

I need to use the Linux bash shell to do it. If any one could help me I be very grateful.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date formats in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash)

Answer (score 3):

When performance matters. Put this in `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN{ 
  m["Jan"]="01"; m["Feb"]="02"; m["Mar"]="03"; m["Apr"]="04"; 
  m["May"]="05"; m["Jun"]="06"; m["Jul"]="07" # to be completed
}
{
  print $1, $2, m[$4] "/" $5 "/" $8
}
```

Usage: `awk -f script.awk logfile`

Output:

```
ok: servername 05/23/2018
ok: servername 07/16/2019
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `date`, you can specify an input file containing all your date strings; combined with `cut` and `paste`:

```sh
paste -d ' ' \
    <(cut -d ' ' -f-2 infile) \
    <(date -f <(cut -d ' ' -f3- infile) '+%m/%d/%Y')
```

Output:

```
ok: servername 05/23/2018
ok: servername 07/16/2019
```

This uses process substitution to build a temporary input file for `date -f`, and for `paste` to build a new output file.