# Convert Data format in awk variable

Tags: awk

I've below file and need to convert its date format to `YYYY-MM-DD` by using `awk`. Sample content of `File.TXT`

```
1;ABC;SSS;Mar 12, 2020;4;1;0;5;0;0;0;0
2;DEF;AAA;Apr 14, 2020;4;1;0;5;0;0;0;0
```

Expecting output

```
1;ABC;SSS;2020-03-12;4;1;0;5;0;0;0;0
2;DEF;AAA;2020-04-14;4;1;0;5;0;0;0;0
```

Comment: On SO we encourage users to show their efforts in form of code, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting date strings in a file with linux bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61015078/formatting-date-strings-in-a-file-with-linux-bash-shell)

Comment: I used this command and its not working .. cat File.txt | awk -F ';' '{OFS="|"} {print $(date -d $3 +"%Y%m%d")}'

Answer (score 0):

This script should do the trick:

```
BEGIN{
    FS=";"
    OFS=";"
    month["Jan"] = "01"
    month["Feb"] = "02"
    month["Mar"] = "03"
    month["Apr"] = "04"
    month["May"] = "05"
    month["Jun"] = "06"
    month["Jul"] = "07"
    month["Aug"] = "08"
    month["Sep"] = "09"
    month["Oct"] = "10"
    month["Nov"] = "11"
    month["Dec"] = "12"
}
{
    split($4,date," ")
    $4 = date[3]"-"gsub(",","",date[2])"-"month[date[1]]
    print
}
```

call with `awk -f script.awk youinput.txt`