# grep date in truststore

Tags: grep, format

I have result after grep truststore.jks

Command for grep

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ./truststore.jks -storepass **** | grep "until"
```

Result

```
Valid from: Mon Jun 04 13:17:22 MSK 2018 until: Fri Jun 04 13:27:21 MSK 2038
Valid from: Mon Jun 04 16:17:00 MSK 2018 until: Sun Jun 04 16:27:00 MSK 2023
Valid from: Mon Mar 07 12:35:36 MSK 2022 until: Sun Mar 07 12:45:36 MSK 2027
```

Then i need to get only date after "until:" but in format like 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS'

Result must be

```
04-06-2038 13:27:21
04-06-2023 16:27:00
07-03-2027 12:45:36
```

I do it for task, which can monitoring when certificates will be end

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: See: [Formatting date strings in a file with linux bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61015078/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus thank you for hint about formatting date strings
Maybe you can help with parse string "Valid from: Mon Jun 04 13:17:22 MSK 2018 until: Fri Jun 04 13:27:21 MSK 2038" to "Fri Jun 04 13:27:21 MSK 2038"