# UNIX Date Utility

Tags: date, unix

I need to pull the day given a specific date. For example, I will provide the date format of 2021_11_06 and the shell will provide "Sat" without quotes.

I know that I can get the current day by:
$ date '+%a'

However, I need to provide the day given a specified date.

Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: What OS or version of date? On Mac you can do something like `date -j -f"%Y%M%d" "20211106" '+%a'`, but I think it will be different for GNU.

Comment: Sun OS Oracle Solaris 10 1/13

I tried the following without success:
date -j -f '%Y_%m_%d' "2021_11_06" +'%a'

Comment: I don't think Solaris' built-in `date` has a `-d` option like GNU, but there are some good options at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash. The `awk` solution might be a good place to start since it avoids the differences in `date`.

Comment: The -d option is not availabel to Solaris. I will take a look at awk.

Comment: I do not have a Solaris with me right now, but there are a lot of gnu utilities under /usr/ucb (or they can be installed there).  Maybe date is one of those?