# Convert string to date and compare dates in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

I need to take string as a input covert to date and compare with current date in ksh need something as below

```
read expdate
today=`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`
expD =`$expdate +"%d-%m-%Y"` -- this is not working
if [today -gt expD] ; then
  echo "Today is greater"
else
  echo " Today is gone"
```

Comment: Use format %Y%m%d and then the inequality (as an integer or string) will work.

Comment: @JeffHolt how to format the expdate from string to date ?

Comment: Convert the user-entered string to a date in a different format. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508819/convert-date-formats-in-bash) will probably help.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): show us a possible user input

Comment: @GillesQuénot expdate would be "03-02-2022" , expD needs to be 2022-02-03, something like this

Comment: @JeffHolt `date -d` is not working for ksh

Comment: `date` is not from `ksh`. Which OS do you run? And you don't provide a `date -d` example

Comment: And add `03-02-2022` to your post by editing it

Comment: Please tell me you're not using AIX.

Comment: @Jason please update the question to indicate the format of `expdate` and whether or not your user knows to enter date in said format; right now ... `03-02-2022` could be `MM-DD-YYYY` or `DD-MM-YYYY` .... which is it?

Comment: consider entering your code block, along with an appropriate shebang (eg, `#!/bin/ksh`), at [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the suggested changes; once that code comes back clean then update the question with the latest/clean set of code

Comment: There are several different problems with this code. Note that we expect each question to be about _one_ specific technical issue.

Comment: @JeffHolt i m using aix 7

Answer (score 0):

Since the input date format seems to be either MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY, it is not necessary to have a `date` that understands `-d`. A simple numeric comparison is enough:

```
IFS=- read d m y
if [ $(date +%Y%m%d) -gt "$y$m$d" ]; then
    echo "Today is greater"
else
    echo " Today is gone"
fi
```

Swap `m` and `d` in the `read` command, if necessary.

Add appropriate error-checking for the input format.

Comment: What do you mean by 'As long as the year isn't too distant from today' ? Before JC Christian calendar?? Do you have a wrong example?

Comment: @GillesQuénot, ...well, the year 123 wouldn't do, neither would the year 12345; need the same number of digits on both sides.

Comment: @GillesQuénot I forgot we aren't converting the input.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy actually, both 3 and 5 digit years should work fine for a numerical comparison

Comment: You're right -- I was thinking alpha.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy perl got it right with `gt`,`ne` etc for strings and `>`,`!=`, etc for numbers