# Grep log file greater than time stamp

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

I have a unix log file(application.log), that has logs with timestamp at the starting. I need to search for a pattern "sent" in this log file  greater than time 2014-03-20 14:05:54.

```
2014-03-20 14:05:54,038 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:54,164 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:54,298 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:54,414 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:54,787 [NfxAgent....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter log file entries based on date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706095/filter-log-file-entries-based-on-date-range)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I added 2 more records to the test data to ensure this is really working:

```
2014-03-19 14:05:53,999 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:53,164 [NfxAgent....
```

But I don't think you can use `grep` for this. Here is an awk solution:

```
$ grep sent  grepTest_20140321.txt|  awk '$0 > "2014-03-20 14:05:54"' 
2014-03-20 14:05:54,038 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:54,164 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:54,298 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:54,414 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:54,787 [NfxAgent....
```

**edit**

"What if we need to specify the end time in the same format like 2014-03-21 10:04:14,018?"

And I've added 3 lines of test data to confirm the 2nd case:

```
2014-03-21 10:04:14,017 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-21 10:04:14,018 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-22 10:04:14,999 [NfxAgent....
```

Result shows one new record in the range you've specified.

```
 awk '$0 ~ "sent" && $0 > "2014-03-20 14:05:54" && $0 < "2014-03-21 10:04:14,018"'    grepTest_20140321.txt
2014-03-20 14:05:54,038 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:54,164 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:54,298 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:54,414 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-20 14:05:54,787 [NfxAgent....
2014-03-21 10:04:14,017 [NfxAgent....
```

IHTH

Comment: What if we need to specify the end time in the same format like 2014-03-21 10:04:14,018?

Comment: +1 for `awk '$0 > "2014-03-20 14:05:54"'`, but you're missing the additional search for pattern "sent".

Comment: See edit for solution. To be exact, you'd change ,018 to 019 or user `<=` on the 2nd condtion. Good luck.

Comment: @mklement0 : I've updated my original answer for your case and +1 to you for your good eyes, missed that. But .... its not in the sample data.

Comment: @shellter: Thanks for the update; I also suggest integrating the search for `"sent"` directly into the `awk` program so that there's no need for a separate `grep` command (as in my answer).

Comment: @mklement0 : now the O.P. can pick and choose. Often, with command-line work,  it is convenient to do a grep for the basic filtering and the layer on more stuff as needed. If doing a script, then your more efficient method is definitely the way to go. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
sed -n '/^2014-03-20 14:05:54/,$ {/sent/p;}' file
```

Note: This assumes that there is at least 1 line in your log file that actually starts with `2014-03-20 14:05:54` and that it's OK to include matches from that second in time.

If the existence of such a line is not guaranteed, @shellter's `awk` approach is superior; to put it together:

```
awk '$0 > "2014-03-20 14:05:54" && $0 ~ "sent"' file
```