# How to escape "[" in gsub in awk?

Tags: bash, awk, gsub

I am trying to parse the date-time part from the following -

```
[Tue Oct  4 11:55:19 2016] [hphp] [25376:7f5d57bff700:279809:000001] [] \nFatal error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ')' in /var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/openx/www/delivery/postGetAd.php(12479)(62110d90541a84df30dd077ee953e47c) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

With the following command -

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logwarn -d /tmp/logwarn -p /mnt/log/hiphop/error_`(date +'%Y%m%d')`.log "^.*Fatal*" | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5}'
```

I get the following output (with the brackets `[]`) -

```
[Wed Oct 5 09:49:49 2016]
```

I want to get only the date-time part and then do some comparison. See my other question [Parsing lines from a log file containing date-time greater than something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853960/parsing-lines-from-a-file-containing-date-time-greater-than-something)

I tried using gsub to replace the brackets, but it gives me the following error -

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logwarn -d /tmp/logwarn -p /mnt/log/hiphop/error_`(date +'%Y%m%d')`.log "^.*Fatal*" | awk '{ gsub("/\[\","T",$1); print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5}'
```

Output -

```
awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: Invalid regular expression: /[/
```

It seems I need to escape the `[`. I tried using `\[` but with no success. Output -

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['
awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: Invalid regular expression: /[/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "[Wed Oct 5 09:49:49 2016]"|tr -d '[]'
```

Comment: This would also work it seems. Need to fit it in my case though.

Comment: Verified that this works, even though it removes all the `[` and `]` occuring in the logs, which is fine in my case.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `/.../` regex syntax, you can escape with a single backslash:

```
$ echo '[abc]' | awk '{ gsub(/\[/,"") }1'
abc]
```

Or you can use string-literal syntax, but then you need an extra backslash, (because when the string gets resolved to a regex, the `\\[` becomes the desired `\[`).

```
$ echo '[abc]' | awk '{ gsub("\\[","") }1'
abc]
```

Similarly, to remove both opening and closing brackets:

```
$ echo '[abc]' | awk '{ gsub(/[\[\]]/,"") }1'
abc
```

or

```
$ echo '[abc]' | awk '{ gsub("[\\[\\]]","") }1'
abc
```

Comment: `echo '[ABC]' | awk '{gsub(/[[\]]/,"") } 1'` returns ´ABC´ as well.

Comment: Good point, @JamesBrown. Interestingly, so does `gsub(/[][]/,"")`.

Comment: Using your answer, ` /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logwarn -d /tmp/logwarn -p /mnt/log/hiphop/error_20161006.log "^.*Fatal*" | awk 'gsub(/\[/,"",$1); gsub(/\]/,"",$5);' | awk '{print $5}'` gives me the following output - `2016
2016]
2016
2016]`. Not sure, why the `]` remains in alternative lines. Whereas with @VIPIN KUMAR's answer, it works fine.

Comment: What is the role of the `1` at the end of the code `}1'`?

Comment: @SanderW.vanderLaan, the `1` is shorthand for `{ print $0 }` as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262869/why-does-1-in-awk-print-the-current-line