# extracting row from a file by providing the specified time interval using shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file containing the following columns `Operation,Name,Start_Time,End_time,Status`.

The column Start_Time contains both date and time.

Here is  from the table.

```
Upload | XYZ | 22/10/2014 22:00:00 | 22/10/2014 22:15:10 | finished

Upload | ABC | 22/10/2014 22:10:00 | 22/10/2014 22:30:00 | failed

Upload | EFG | 22/10/2014 23:00:00 | 22/10/2014 23:30:00 | failed
```

I need to extract the rows whose start_time lies between `22:00:00` and `23:00:00` both inclusive.

I tried using awk command. But couldn't succeed.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Shreyas

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find entries in log file within \[timespan\] (eg. the last hour)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706095/find-entries-in-log-file-within-timespan-eg-the-last-hour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F\| '$3~/(22:..:..)|(23:00:00)/' inputFile
```

gives output as

```
Upload | XYZ | 22/10/2014 22:00:00 | 22/10/2014 22:15:10 | finished
Upload | ABC | 22/10/2014 22:10:00 | 22/10/2014 22:30:00 | failed
Upload | EFG | 22/10/2014 23:00:00 | 22/10/2014 23:30:00 | failed
```

**EXPLANATION :**

`-F\|` set input field seperator as `|`

`$3~/(22:..:..)|(23:00:00)/` select lines in which column 3, `$3` follows given pattern

`(22:..:..)` matches any time begining with `22`

`(23:00:00)` matches `23:00:00`

**EDIT**

When columns are delimited by space

```
$ awk  '$4~/(22:..:..)|(23:00:00)/' sam
Upload  XYZ  22/10/2014 22:00:00  22/10/2014 22:15:10  finished
Upload  ABC  22/10/2014 22:10:00  22/10/2014 22:30:00  failed
Upload  EFG  22/10/2014 23:00:00  22/10/2014 23:30:00  failed
```

Comment: does it match for any date?? or only for the specified date ie., 22/10/2014?

Comment: actually there is no field separator as | in the file. There are spaces between the columns. How to sort out then?

Comment: I have one more question.. Can I give a filename as pattern in the script instead of the time I have specified? like..                      $awk '4~/(filename)|(filename)/' sample ..the file contains the time interval

Comment: can this purpose be fulfilled by using sql queries? Start_time is a datetime field in the database.

Comment: the above columns in the file are present in a database..so i wanted to know if an sql query could be written to retrieve the values just like the above output ? That is by providing the time interval within a query..

Comment: it can be done without the use of regex. like `hour(column) = '23'`