# How to accurately grab logs in the past hour from a log file in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have a log file for cron jobs with entries using the format of

```
Mar  8 17:30:01 hostname CROND[PROC_#]: (user) CMD (/path/to/job/)
```

I want to be able to periodically checks the logs to see if a specific CRON job ( that runs hoursly) ran. Finding the logs I want have been easy via grep.

```
grep name_of_job logfile
```

But I'm unsure of how to accurately grab only the logs from the **past hour** to see if any cron jobs have ran.

I tried using the **awk** command to grab the last hour [based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7714878/5641538) but I've had issues with **awk** because my datestamp is separated into multiple fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrt your problem I have created dummy logs, also note that time is wrt to my timezone. I have also displayed the current time before running the script.

```
$ cat file2
Mar  9 05:20:01 hostname CROND[PROC_#]: (user) CMD (/path/to/job/)
Mar  9 04:20:01 hostname CROND[PROC_#]: (user) CMD (/path/to/job/)
Mar  9 05:35:01 hostname CROND[PROC_#]: (user) CMD (/path/to/job/)
Mar  5 05:35:01 hostname CROND[PROC_#]: (user) CMD (/path/to/job/)
Mar  9 04:35:01 hostname CROND[PROC_#]: (user) CMD (/path/to/job/)
$ date
Wed Mar  9 05:40:10 IST 2016
$ ./script.bash 
Mar  9 05:20:01 hostname CROND[PROC_#]: (user) CMD (/path/to/job/)
Mar  9 05:35:01 hostname CROND[PROC_#]: (user) CMD (/path/to/job/)
$
```

Contents of `script.bash` are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    log_date_str="$(awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3}' <<< "$line")"
    log_date="$(date -d "$log_date_str" +%s)"
    [[ $(($(date +%s)-$log_date)) -le 3600 ]] && echo "$line"
done < "file2"
```

we get the date from the log file and convert it into number of seconds elapsed since [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and also get that same format for current datetime from command `date +%s` Note `+%s` is the format here. `date -d dateString +%s` can be used to parse a string as date into a desired format.

Once we have both the dates we just subtract it and then find out those results which have difference less than 3600 seconds(1 hour); and then we just print out the log line.

Instead of passing the filename to the `while` loop you can pass your ouput of `grep`

Comment: Thanks, it works great, can you explain what the "while read..." line does?

Comment: it reads the file line by line, using the `read` shell builtin, `help read` for more info. in short it reads each line of file into a variable called `line`(successfully read returns 0 exit code) or also checks if length of `line` variable is not 0 using `[[ -n line]]`(this is needed when line doesnt end in a newline char(`\n`), for example: last line)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in GNU awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS="[ :]+"
    nowSecs  = systime()
    thisYear = strftime("%Y")
}
{
    mthNr = (match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$1)+2)/3
    inSecs = mktime(thisYear" "mthNr" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5)
}
(nowSecs - inSecs) <= 60
$ awk -f tst.awk file
```

If your input file and the current date can cross year boundaries then you'd need to add some logic to handle it since your input file doesn't contain a year.

Comment: Thanks I already implemented the other guys because it worked and he posted first but I like your answer and like the little trick you did with the long month string :).

Comment: Thanks. You might want to read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice before trying to use a shell loop to manipulate text.