# How to extract last 10 min from apache log

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I'm trying to parse apache log and print log entires generated in last n number of minutes

Sample of my access log data is [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/mdsceC0L)  and this is what I have tried so far:

**update** The following solution works

```
awk -vDate=$(date -d'now-10 minutes' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S) '$4 > Date {print Date, $0}' access.log
```

Comment: This approach isn't going to work well. The day isn't going to change in the last hour except right after midnight so you need a date format that includes the minutes. That's easy, the problem is that won't necessarily match any line in your input so you can't use a range like that. Use something else for this. Like `awk` or an actual tool designed to parse/handle apache logs (there are many of them).

Comment: Can you suggest any tool that I might be able to use to do that? I'm more interested in getting access data by time.

Comment: Try `awk -vDate=$(date -d'now-10 minutes' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S) '$4 > Date {print Date, $0}' access.log` from [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7714878/3776858).

Comment: That seems to work! Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate.