# Filter log for last minutes \ hours

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I want filter a file, and delete (or write to another file), only strings which Date are "realy" smaller then Date now, lets say for 2 hours 30 minutes ago (150 minutes). I don't need command which can find something like absolute value "2017-03-21 04:36:19" - and then delete all lines before. Because it`s a big chance that lines is not exist (seconds, then minutes, and this filter give all the file without deleting).

I have data in next format:

```
2017-03-18 01:27:12 bla bla
2017-03-18 02:14:11 bla bla
2017-03-20 04:37:14 bla bla
2017-03-21 02:25:59 bla bla
2017-03-22 05:12:43 bla bla
```

Time format:
%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

I search on google, and try everything on first page by many search queries.

Comment: See: [Find entries in log file within timespan eg. the last hour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7706095/3776858)

Comment: What's the problem? You are using a sane date format, so you can simply use string comparison.

Comment: *smaller then Date now, lets say for 2 hours 30 minutes ago (150 minutes)* - ok, today is `2017-03-27`. They are all smaller

Comment: @MichaelVehrs i realy trying to use these commands, exact from this post wich are you give me, but it dosn't work for me. Your answer exactly do what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk:

```
awk '
BEGIN{ now=systime() }     # now in seconds 
{
    then=$1 " " $2         # then might not be a good var name though :)
    gsub(/[-:]/," ",then)  # making mktime fit variable out of then
    then=mktime(then)      # then then to seconds
    if(then < now-604800)  # compare, 604800 is 7 days in seconds
        print              # output older than that
}' file
2017-03-18 01:27:12 bla bla
2017-03-18 02:14:11 bla bla
2017-03-20 04:37:14 bla bla
```

Comment: Thank you! Its works too (not for my goal).

Its give me older then 7 days. Thats nice too. Maybe exist "inverse" option for awk, as in 'sed', so it can give just 7 days, or 150 minutes.

Comment: @Amaroc Just change the 604800 in the code to which ever time you want (in seconds), I had to use such value since your data was such. If you want only newer than 150 minutes: `if(then > now-9000)`.

Comment: Thank you for help again, i will use this one (this one simple for read): 

awk -vdate=$(date -d "150 minutes ago" '+%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S') \
    '$1$2 >= date { print }' log
But yours method is also good and as i see it can parse another date format [-:]/," " so its cute!

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -vdate=$(date -d "150 minutes ago" '+%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S') \
    '$1$2 >= date { print }' log
```

Comment: OMG, are you genius, i use same "commands" withe same syntaxis, but it never  works. Thank you very much!