# Extract Only Lines Of 4 days using grep or awk

Tags: python, php, unix, awk, grep

Hello I have a text file with below entries

```
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-22_120712.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-22_120947.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-23_153159.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-23_153434.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-24_053634.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-24_053910.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-25_053255.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-25_053530.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-26_055307.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-26_055542.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-27_063328.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-27_063603.zi
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-01_210715.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-01_210950.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-02_033726.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-02_034001.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-03_064238.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-03_064513.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-04_043117.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-04_043353.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-05_050735.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-05_051010.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-06_073457.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-06_073733.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-07_033928.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-07_034204.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-08_014822.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-08_015059.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-09_033301.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-09_033537.zip
```

I want to select only files between [today's date -4days] & [to whichever old date]

I tried to search on something like this but couldn't find anything :(

Can anyone please help me with any grep, awk command or any small php or python script which can do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter log file entries based on date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706095/filter-log-file-entries-based-on-date-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interesting thing about your entries that is a really good practice is to have a **naming convention**, and the best is that you use a `YYYY-MM-DD` **date format**. This format is interesting because you just have **compare string values to get which one is newer**. For exemple if you have `'2020-10-25'`, it's greater than `'2020-10-20'` and it's also newer in time. So you can use a simple lexicographic comparison like that :

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta  

#the file in which are the entries 
filename = 'your_file' 

#creating a start date by takin current date and subtracting 4 days
startDate = (datetime.datetime.today() + timedelta(days=-4)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 

endDate = '2020-10-08' #whatever date you want

startFile = 'MySql-DataBase-' + startDate
endFile = 'MySql-DataBase-' + endDate

#open the file and get all entries
with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
myFiles = [x.strip() for x in content]

# Adding all the file that name is between startFile and endFile
res = [file for  file in myFiles if startFile < file < endFile]

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    cmd="date +\"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S\" -d \"-4 days\""  # get date 4 days ago
    if((cmd|getline dt)<=0)                         # if getline did not work
        exit                                        # exit
} 
$0<"MySql-DataBase-" dt' file                       # compare and conditionally output
```

Output:

```
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-22_120712.zip
...
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-05_050735.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-05_051010.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

If (and only if) the dates reflected in file names is reflected in actual file creation date.

You can better use `find` command.

```
find . -type f -name "*.zip" -ctime 4
```